# How do I get an instance of RSAPrivateKey

Tags: java, cryptography

How do I create an instance of [java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey.html) given RSA's `d`, `e` and `n` (let's assume as BigIntegers). (Here `d` denotes the private exponent, `e` the public exponent and `n=pq` the RSA modulus.)

I thought this would be really simple but I can't find anything in the documentation or the internet in general.

If that it is any help, I already have BouncyCastle installed.

**Edit** to clarify: I'm looking for a class that implements the interface and takes `d`, `e` and/or `n` as arguments to the constructor (or argument to a factory function, etc.) as opposed to creating a new, random key or reading the key from a file in some PKCS* format.

Comment: I do not assume that you are trying to get an instance of an interface, so what is you plan here? Do you want to know how to create a class that implements that interface oder what are you looking for? I feel like i'm missing something crucial in your question.

Comment: @Akunosh: I'm looking for a class that implements the interface and takes d, e and n as arguments, as opposed to creating a new, random key or reading the key from a file in some PKCS* format. I would prefer using an existing class, but if I have to implement it myself, so be it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, here is how you can construct one given the private exponent and modulus ( all that is required for the private key ):

```
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    RSAPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(
            new BigInteger("57791d5430d593164082036ad8b29fb157791d5430d593164082036ad8b29fb157791d5430d593164082036ad8b29fb157791d5430d593164082036ad8b29fb1", 16),
            new BigInteger("57791d5430d593164082036ad8b29fb157791d5430d593164082036ad8b29fb157791d5430d593164082036ad8b29fb157791d5430d593164082036ad8b29fb1", 16)
    );

    RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason at all to use the Bouncy Castle provider for this kind of functionality. You should only use BC if Java doesn't contain the required functionality. You can do this by not specifying the provider.

Comment: Agree that answer using default provider is better, updated.  Incidentally when using the Oracle JDK 8's default provider it enforces a minimum key size of 512 bits, which the BC provider does not.  So in this case the BC provider is more flexible (useful if, for whatever reason, you want to do something with a, say, 256 bit key).